# How to solve the random walk problem on the complete graph?

Tags: probability, random-walk

In a complete graph of order $n$, a moving point starts from a certain vertex and moves along the edges. At each vertex, the unpassed edges are selected with equal probability to continue the movement. What is the expectation of the number of passed edges until it stops its movement?

The moving point probably does not pass all the edges. It just needs to move into a vertex and cannot move out.

Comment: For $n$ odd, the trail may not pass every edge. For example, it is possible to pass just $6$ edges on $K_5$ before you run out of places to go.

Comment: I think you maybe misunderstand the problem

Comment: Let's suppose the $5$ vertices of $K_5$ are labeled 1,2,3,4,5. Suppose you start at $1$ and go on the following edges: $1-2$, $2-3$, $3-1$, $1-4$, $4-5$, $5-1$. Then you have exhausted every edge leaving $1$ while only taking $6$ total edges.

Comment: ok,it's my mistake.

Comment: @subrosar, why only for $K_n$ with $n$ odd? it seems to me that you can find an example similar to your $K_5$ also for $K_4$.

Comment: @mrc ntn, that was in response to something lixingyu originally posted and then removed about the odd case.

Comment: This problem is difficult because it is not Markov, that is, the state of the walk depends on information about which edges it has used previously. The version of this problem where edges can be re-used and we only care about how many steps before returning to the original vertex is comparatively easy, even for an arbitrary graph.

Comment: Some values for small $n$ are $f(1)=0, f(2)=1, f(3)=3, f(4)=19/4, f(5)=254/27, f(6)=91/8$

Comment: I also got that $f(7) = 552857/28125$. If anyone was wondering, I wrote an inefficient program to brute-force the paths. $f(7)$ took $250$ seconds to calculate.

Comment: @VVejalla for curiosity, did you find also $f(8)$ and $f(9)$ ? or you didn't want to "burn" your laptop? :)

Comment: @mrcntn It was taking way too long, so I aborted the computation. My program is very inefficient, almost a complete brute-force.

Comment: Wow, I didn't try but it seems a nice computational challenge. maybe I will try to think about a numerical solution next week end.. However, if $f(7)$ takes 250 seconds, I would expect $f(8)$ to take $\sim 250 * (8-2)$ seconds or so (let's say 1 hour more or less..), which is still a "human time". Maybe we should look for a non exact algorithm. Note: I guessed $~250*(8-2)$ because of this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2406920/532409 ... but it's a pure guess.

Comment: @VVejalla how to calculate it on computer?

Comment: Just brute force through all possible paths. There are some optimizations possible - at the first step and second steps, it doesn't matter what node the point moves to; at the next step, moving back to the first node and moving to a new one are the only two options, etc. I don't know of a way to generalize this, so my program is very slow.